Enable 2FA with push Notification with Azure Adb2C
I want to enable push notification through Microsoft Authentication App for MFA with Azure Active Directory with adb2c. By default there are user flow with Email, SMS, Phone Call and Timed OTP flow(Through Authenticator app). Can anyone help by suggesting the way to achieve the same?
I have tried user flows with condition access policies as well but it does not work.
Also checked couple of documentation from Microsoft. Look like its not support the flow. Is it possible with other apps like OKTA or DUO?
Using 2 factor authentication with Azure Ad b2c and the authenticator App

You would have to look at the partner offerings here to see if any of them offer this.
